# LinkedIn SDK for objective-c (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linkedin-api

I want to make an iphone app that can update statues and share linkes on linkedin

any one can help me please

thanx

Comment: You should start here: http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis

Comment: I use this sdk
 
http://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone
 
read readme file before use it

Answer (score 3):

you have to check for the parameters like consumer and access token etc.

https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html

or

https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone