# Linkedin-iPhone framework not working

Tags: iphone, linkedin-api

After lookin for some good solution for authenticating with linkedIn i found several references to https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone
([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809036/linkedin-connectivity-from-my-native-iphone-application) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442833/linkedin-sdk-for-objective-c-iphone))

Unfortunately the demo code is not working : i enter my consumerKey and secret but the authentication screen stays white, nothing happens, nothing is logged...

When debugging i found that the synchronous call in OADataFetcher is failing with NSURLErrorDomain error -1012

The URL it tries to call is : https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken

(the same url works fine on safari)

Does anybody knows why this could be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I hope this help you
http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/2151